# How can I return an object with a list inside of it?

Tags: c#

My code looks like this right now:

```
return Ok(new
{
     error = "Username not found",
     errors = "Username not found",
     success = false
});
```

and

```
return Ok(new
{
     error = "Username not found",
     errors = results.Errors,
     success = false
});
```

What I would like to do is to make errors into a list of strings and then in the first return have the first element of the list set to "Username not found". I would also like to have a class for this instead of new but should I use a private or a public class?

Can someone give me some advice on how I could do this?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and post what you come up with?

Comment: `errors = new[] { "Username not found" }.Concat(results.Errors).ToList()`

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does this code do, what changes do you want to make and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go with private constructor than you have to expose this by another public API - for example static method. So you have two options one is public constructor or property initializer.

Finally making a list of errors is easy way and Lucas Trzesniewski gave you example of it.

Version with public constrcutor:

```
public class Ok
{
    public Ok(IList<string> errors, bool success)
    {
        this.Errors = errors;
        this.Success = success;
    }

    public IList<string> Errors { get; set; }

    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

Version with private constructor:

```
public class Ok
{
    private Ok(IList<string> errors, bool success)
    {
        this.Errors = errors;
        this.Success = success;
    }

    public IList<string> Errors { get; set; }

    public bool Success { get; set; }

    public static Ok Create(IList<string> errors, bool success)
    {
        return new Ok(errors, success);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me what you mean by a private constructor.  I was thinking I needed a class as I have this same object in many places.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at response, you could use the built-in methods in Web API to simplify this.

For instance, the `success` property of your response highlights that the response was probably not **OK** and should probably be a **BadRequest**.

You could use ModelState to return a list of errors, built-up throughout the method. For example in your controller:

```
if (!userFound) {
    ModeState.AddModelError("Username", "Username not found");
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

In this instance I would suggest using the built-in constructs to handle errors. This way you do not need an extra class to client errors.